# MongoDB trying to store profile id and user id to a JWT payload when a user logs in

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, jwt, payload

In my MERN stack app when a user logs in, a JWT payload is created and is used to to sign a JWT token. And when someone wants to post an article, the route will first check the token to make sure it is valid. Then if it's good then a new article object will be created from the req.body, and the user details such as user.id to help keep track of who created the article. My Post route so far:

```
// @route   POST api/articles
// @desc    Create article 
// @access  Private
router.post(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const { errors, isValid } = validatePostInput(req.body);

    var tags;

    // Tags - Split into array
    if (typeof req.body.tags !== "undefined") {
      tags = req.body.tags.split(",");
    }

    const newArticle = new Article({
      user: req.user.id, // From the JWT Token
      text: req.body.text,
      headline: req.body.headline,
      fullheaderimage: req.body.fullheaderimage,
      articleheaderimage: req.body.articleheaderimage,
      tags: tags
    });

    newArticle.save().then(article => res.json(article));

  }
);
```

Right now the payload contains user auth details such as the user.id, user.name, avatar, user.role. These come from my User Model.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'subscriber'
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

This works fine but now I'm trying to add details from my Profile Model, to the JWT Payload, and when a user creates an article it will also contain a relation to my Profile Model as well a my user Model. This is where I'm running into problems. I'm referencing my Profile Model correctly when it comes to posting an article. When a user logs in I'm able to successfully add their profile.id to the JWT Payload, here is the login route.

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = validateLoginInput(req.body);

  // Check Validation
  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  // Find user by email
  User.findOne({ email }).then((user) => {
    // Check for user
    if (!user) {
      errors.email = "User Not Found";
      return res.status(404).json(errors);
    }

    // Find a matching profile for user
    Profile.findOne({ user: user.id }).then((profile) => {

      //Check Password
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then((isMatch) => {
        if (isMatch) {
          //User Matched

          // Create JWT Payload
          const payload = { 
              id: user.id, 
              name: user.name,  
              avatar: user.avatar, 
              role: user.role,
              profile: profile.id  
            };

          //Sign Token
          jwt.sign(
            payload,
            keys.secretOrKey,
            { expiresIn: 259200 },
            (err, token) => {
              res.json({
                success: true,
                token: "Bearer " + token,
              });
            }
          );
        } else {
          errors.password = "password incorrect";
          return res.status(400).json(errors);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

But now when I try to update the post route to also reference the Profile Model I get an error.
Updated section of post route

```
  const newArticle = new Article({
      user: req.user.id, // Comes from JWT Token
      profile: req.profile.id, // Errors on this line
      text: req.body.text,
      headline: req.body.headline,
      fullheaderimage: req.body.fullheaderimage,
      articleheaderimage: req.body.articleheaderimage,
      tags: tags
    })
```

Error I get

```
Cannot read property id of undefined
```

Just for verification I copied the token I get and used this site here https://jwt.io/ to check
to make sure that the correct profile id is contained in the payload, and it is. So now I'm at a loss as to what I could be missing.

Comment: `req.user` is set by passport.js. Naturally, it knows nothing about your `profile`, so it doesn't set `req.profile`. Anyway, do you _need_ to add this piece to the token? You can look this up by user id, why bloat the token?

Comment: Yeah I see what you are saying. For whatever reason I completely overlooked that part. There are a few fields in my Profile model that I wanted to use. But yeah you're right I could just look it up by user id. Thanks for the heads up.